# exchange 2010 multitenant install setup.com problem

Tags: exchange-2010

Im new to exchange and want to test out exch 2010 in a hyper-v vm.

Im using win 2008 r2, believe I have installed all the prerequisites.

I try to install using setup in /hosting mode using the following command from the directory that I copied all the exchange install files to:

setup.com /m:install /r:m,ca,ht /hosting /on:testtest

The setup however does not start and I get the following message:

Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Setup Help 
Please type one of the below options for detailed Help about each subject: 
Setup.com /help:Install - Installing Exchange Server roles

etc.....

I've carefully checked for typos and I just can't seem to figure out what seems to be the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image attached because I don't have enough points?

http://www.securems.com/exchangeproblem.png

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was pretty simple, I was not using a SP1 install DVD and the /hosting switch apparently only works with sp1.